# Adding a button to <%= link_to_add_fields "Add A Present", f, :presents %> in Rails?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, forms, button

I can't figure out how to add a button to a link_to_add_fields as in

```
<%= link_to_add_fields "Add A Present", f, :presents %>
```

in Rails App I'm making.

I tried adding, `class: "btn btn-mini btn-info"` everywhere, but I keep getting an error about number of arguments.

It works for example in this line:

```
<%= f.link_to_remove "Remove this present", class: "btn btn-mini btn-info" %>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: and what if you do <%= button_to_add_fields "Add A Present", f, :presents %> and then give it a class?

Comment: undefined method `button_to_add_fields' for #<#<Class:0x54abdf8>:0x3e12d00>

Comment: <%= button_to_add_fields "Add A Present", f, :presents, class:  "btn btn-mini btn-info"  %>

Comment: Nope it does not. Still the same.

Comment: Can you give the full stacktrace of the error please?

Answer (score 6):

I am assuming you made this helper from the rails cast episode http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2.

In your application_helper.rb, you have defined link_to_add_fields. Probably something like this.

`def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)`

change it to this

`def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association, locals={})`

Then on the return statement.

`link_to_function(name, "add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")", class: locals[:class])`

Finally, use your new method like so

`<%= link_to_add_fields "Add A Present", f, :presents, class: "btn btn-mini btn-info" %>`

Answer (score 0):

Based off @Aeisme's response I had to hack together a solution for Rails 4.1 users.

application_helper.rb

```
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association, locals={})
```

return value for link_to_add_fields function

```
link_to(name, '#', class: [locals[:class], "add_fields"], data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
```

Answer (score 0):

Allen's answer worked for me! You could also add the button class directly in your helper method.

[see helper method example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxouW.jpg)